# Replace multiple conditions with DRY solution

Tags: python, design-patterns, conditional-statements, dry

I have
A: boolean;
B: boolean;

```py
A=0, B=0: run func1 and func2
A=0, B=1: run func1 and func3
A=1, B=0: run func2
A=1, B=1: run func3
```

Every function has different signatures with a different number of arguments.

Right now i did something like this:

```py
if not A and not B: run func1 and func2
if not A and B: run func1 and func2
if A and not B: run func1 and func2
if A and B: run func1 and func2
```

but instead of calling functions i repeat the same code block for every if statement, i know it's redundant, how can i replace this massive block of if statements into a few line of code calling the right method only once when necessary?

I thought that i could use a mapping Dictionary like this:

```py
mapping_dict = {
    True: {
        True: [func3],
        False: [func2]
    },
    False: {
        True: [func1, func3],
        False: [func1, func2]
    }
```

but even so, i need a solution to determine which arguments to pass the function depending on the function returned by

```py
mapping_dict[A][B]
```

Mine could be a specific case but i would like to know how to approach this kind of problems with a "**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself" solution, is there any pattern for this problem? how does it work? Is it language-indipendent?


Thank you for your patience

Comment: What "different arguments" do the different functions take? you can make them all accept `**kwargs` and then just do `mapping_dict[A][B](**kwargs)`

Comment: I would think about the different function signatures and try to unify them (wrapper functions or an object as single parameter containing all data needed for all functions)

Comment: @DeepSpace You are right but the problem is that the mapping dictionary may return multiple functions, and that would raise an Exception if i call mapping_dict[A][B](**kwargs), do you thing that a for loop would solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You're overcomplicating your conditional:

`func1()` is only dependent on `a`.

`func2()` and `func3()` on `b`.

So you need two independent conditionals:

```
if not a:
    func1()

if b:
    func3()
else:
    func2()
```

This is equivalent because `func2()` & `func3()` truthiness is independent of `a`... this is easier seen if you rearrange your truth statements grouping those functions:

```
A=0, B=0: run func1 and func2
A=1, B=0: run func2

A=0, B=1: run func1 and func3
A=1, B=1: run func3
```

if `b` is zero, `func2()` is run. if `b` is 1, `func3()` is run. In both cases `a` can be 1 or 0.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to get to this solution? Is that possible to visualize with a Truth Table (just for making my ideas clear on what is going on)?

Comment: I added some info on how I reached that conclusion.

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful, anyway do you think there is some procedure that always work when i need to write multiple statements? I mean, this case involve only 2 booleans, but how should i aproach the next time if i have multiple booleans and multiple functions?

Comment: If you have a truth table, use grouping like above to see which values are independent. In most practical cases you shouldn't need a truth table, as ideally the functions should be self explanatory. `a` would be `isCleanData` and `func1()` `CleanData()` so we get `if not isCleanData(): CleanData()` which makes sense without having to produce a truth table if the next step requires clean data.